# Load TIF/TIFF in HTML5 canvas and avoid download

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, xmlhttprequest, tiff

I want to show tiff/tif images inside an HTML5 canvas. Following [this doc](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js) I´ve accomplished to do it with uploaded images but when I need to dynamically reference external images by URL the browser always force the download.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.open('GET', "url/of/a/tiff/image/file.tiff");
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
  var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
  document.body.append(canvas);
};
xhr.send();
```

At the begining I had CORS issues but I solved that problem, now the uploaded images are display correctly but URL are not.

How can I do this for both cases uploaded images and URL

Thanks in advance!

> UPDATE!

Working on later I noticed that when load .tiff files there is no problem. The download is forced when is a .tif file. Are these mime types differents?

Comment: Can you setup a live demo? [Here is a free tiff file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Example.tiff) available online without CORS restrictions that you can use to make a live demo using the snippet editor available by clicking the <> icon.

Comment: with .tiff images is working the problem is with .tif

Comment: I could not find a cdn for the library I'm using and when I include the full library I can't save the post